# Gitlab Pages throw 404 when accessed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pages

I have a group project with the following name (hosted in Gitlab): gitlab.com/my-group/my-project.

I have generated coverage reports during testing and saved them as artifacts using Gitlab CI. Here is Gitlab CI config:

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: node:11
  before_script:
    - npm install -g yarn
    - yarn
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - yarn lint
    - yarn test --all --coverage src/
  except:
    - tags
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/
  coverage: '/Statements\s+\:\s+(\d+\.\d+)%/'

deploy-pages:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - test
  script:
    - mv coverage/ public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public/
    expire_in: 30 days
  except:
    - tags
```

When I open deploy stage job, I can see the artifact being created. Here is the screenshot: [image: Artifact file structure]. All the files are under /public directory in the artifact.

Now, when I go to: https://my-group.gitlab.io/my-project, I keep getting 404.

I am not sure what step I am missing here. Can someone shed some light on this issue for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three [basic requirements](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/#how-it-works) for the project itself:

- project must be named `group.gitlab.io` (if you want it to be the [base domain](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html))
- job must create [artifact in public directory](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started/pages_from_scratch.html#specify-the-public-directory-for-artifacts)
- job must be called `pages`

Most likely it's the last one that needs fixing since your job is currently called `deploy-pages`. Simply rename that to `pages`.

You'll know when you got everything working because under Settings > Pages, it will tell you the link where it's published to.

Comment: The content is organized a bit differently now but I've updated the links to the closest docs content that is there now.